# Away3D vs Sandy 3D and other Flash 3D Engines for Mobile

Tags: flash, mobile, 3d, away3d, sandy3d

What are the pros and cons of various Flash 3D engines with regards to performance on mobile devices? Which do you prefer -- which have you tried (examples of apps developed) implementing on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

I was running Away3D 2 years ago on my Galaxy S (1st gen) at 30fps with a simple scene no problem. Actionscript compiles into AIR apps for android and ios with full Stage3D support.

This isn't a matter of AS2 or AS3, at all. All modern (and even years-old) smartphones will run AIR AS3 Stage3D-powered apps as standalones.

Just go with Away3D if you plan on using AIR. It's officially supported by adobe and is relatively easy to approach, especially if you're comfortable with AS3.

Answer (score -1):

The trouble is that mobile devices often don't support anything beyond Flash 6. You listed Away3D and Sandy3D, which pretty much answers your question-

Out of the two, Sandy3D is the only one compatible with AS2. Away3D is only supported on Flash 9+. So, you don't really have a choice.